# Select2 placeholder

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

In https://select2.github.io/examples.html it teach how to set placeholders on jQuery's plugin Select2. I want to have a placeholder not just in the field, but also in the searchbox. I put an image with the example from the official website and how I need it. This can be done right out of the box or I have t o modify the plugin?

[image]

Comment: I think this post will resolve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819164/how-make-select2-placeholder-for-search-input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How make select2 placeholder for search input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819164/how-make-select2-placeholder-for-search-input)