# How make select2 placeholder for search input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

How to make placeholder for select2 jQuery plugin. On StackOverflow many answers how to make placeholder there, but they about element's placeholder. I need to specify a placeholder for the search box, see pic.[image]

Comment: what have you done so far? have you tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049731/adding-placeholder-attribute-using-jquery

Comment: `$country.select2({
    placeholder: __("Select your country"),
    //todo add search placeholder __('Start typing…')
  });`

Comment: you can try something like this, (".select2-search__field").attr("placeholder",'your placeholder');

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had the same need and I had ended up writing a small extension for the `Select2` plugin.

There is a new option for the plugin, `searchInputPlaceholder`, in order to set a placeholder for the 'search' input field.

Add the following code right after the plugin's js file:

```
(function($) {

    var Defaults = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/defaults');

    $.extend(Defaults.defaults, {
        searchInputPlaceholder: ''
    });

    var SearchDropdown = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/dropdown/search');

    var _renderSearchDropdown = SearchDropdown.prototype.render;

    SearchDropdown.prototype.render = function(decorated) {

        // invoke parent method
        var $rendered = _renderSearchDropdown.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));

        this.$search.attr('placeholder', this.options.get('searchInputPlaceholder'));

        return $rendered;
    };

})(window.jQuery);
```

**Usage:**

Initialize the select2 plugin with the `searchInputPlaceholder` option:

```
$("select").select2({
    // options 
    searchInputPlaceholder: 'My custom placeholder...'
});
```

**Demo:**

Demo available on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3k9xfdxo/).

---

**UPDATE May 9, 2020**

Tested with the latest Select2 Version (**v4.0.13**) - [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6g0e5xLj/).

---

**Github repo:**

https://github.com/andreivictor/select2-searchInputPlaceholder

Comment: Hi thanks for above nice code however this directly renders the whole markup inside select2 search. Any workaround for that? I need to even add fontawesome icon before placeholder.

Comment: why don't you use css for that? you can style `.select2-search` element and insert an icon using `:before` or `:after`

Comment: example: http://jsfiddle.net/3jsr4ywh/21/

Answer (score 12):

You can use the event:

> [select2:opening](https://select2.github.io/options.html#events): Triggered before the dropdown is opened. This event can be prevented

It's enough to add the placeholder attribute in this event:

```
$(this).data('select2').$dropdown.find(':input.select2-search__field').attr('placeholder', 'My Placeholder')
```

```js
$('select').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select an option'
}).on('select2:opening', function(e) {
    $(this).data('select2').$dropdown.find(':input.select2-search__field').attr('placeholder', 'My Placeholder')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you. 
But it looks like a hack. And this function fires every time when I dropdown select.

Comment: @LukasPierce Like suggested in the comment you cannot use anymore with the last version the **$(".hidden").....** because the dropdown is created on the fly every time you open the select2... You can try by yourself that the **container** is created every time. Thanks

Comment: @gaetanoM works fine with my Select2 4.1.0

Comment: @PavelBariev I am very pleased

Answer (score 11):

Use event [select2:open](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events).

```
$('#mySelect').select2().on('select2:open', function(e){
    $('.select2-search__field').attr('placeholder', 'your placeholder');
})
```

Comment: There may be multiple select2 element. Is it possible to avoid affecting others while changing one search bar?

Answer (score -2):

You must add class

`disabled selected hidden`

to first option element of select