# how I can add my Placeholder into my Dropdown Search input

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a dropdown with search functionality I am using select2, I am trying to put my placeholder in to dropdown search input but its not showing anything placeholder.

```
$( ".select2-input" ).select2({ placeholder: "shahzad" } );
```

**here is my working jsfiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/shahzadsiddiqui8/nLoxumwv/

[dropdown Search Input - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWqfa.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How make select2 placeholder for search input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819164/how-make-select2-placeholder-for-search-input)

Answer (score 3):

you can use this:
    `$(".select2-input").attr("placeholder","hi");`

Answer (score 1):

Add in your js code extra line like below

```
$( ".select2-input" ).attr('placeholder','Select State');
```